# How to debug windows phone on windows 8 standard?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

I want to stay windows phone development but I have a windows 8 standard laptop. When I try to debug an app, it says HyperV not installed. Since HyperV is only for windows 8 pro, I can't install it. Is there any way that I can debug my app without purchasing windows 8 pro ?

Answer (score 3):

I think in this case you'll have to do all of your testing as a deployment to your actual test phone.  HyperV is not needed for deployment to the hardware.

It's an unfortunate gotcha for WP development, but you can actually upgrade your OS in place if you can afford it. This will simply "turn on" the hyperV functionality, and has other benefits such as being able to run VMs off of your laptop to sandbox untrusted applications.